# Cant open port on Windows 2012R2

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-server-2012, port

I really never had problem with Windows Firewall, however today on new installation i`m trying to open port 110 but i cant.

My firewall rule is: [printscreen](http://prntscr.com/2nygwt)

```
telnet myip 110
Connecting To myip...Could not open connection to the host, on port 110:
Connect failed
```

If i change "Remote Port" to "Any", everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally implement firewall rules based on destination port. Most applications (client-side) choose a random source port when the initiate communication. For example, your web browser uses random TCP source ports against destination port 80.

So, the correct way to go is to allow destination port 110, source port any.

Heres some background: [Ephemeral ports on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Comment: I dont see any config about source port, only source ip. p.s i never had any problem in the past with rules like this.

Comment: It's called "Remote Port" in the Windows firewall config. You need to set that to "any".

Comment: Sometimes when i work to much, i make funny mistakes :) definitely need a rest